# configure schema registry to be public

Tags: rest, confluent-schema-registry

If I want schema registry to be exposed publicly, how would I go about that? I assume I need to configure the listeners. How would I configure schema registry to allow both HTTP and HTTPS at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It's public, by default, since it binds on all interfaces on port 8081.

Ideally, you'd implement TLS-termination in an L7 proxy, but you can do this, for example to bind to two ports.

```
listeners=https://0.0.0.0:8081,http://0.0.0.0:8082
```